# Importing cert for ssl communication

Tags: java, ssl

We are running an application (developed using Grails) under Amazon EC2 and as part of integration process we are suppose to open SSL communication with a different application. when ever we try to open connection the application is failing with following error message:

> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building
>   failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
>   unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I am assuming we have o import certificate in cacert, but in this case as we do not have access to installed JVM, I don't think we can do that. Is there any other way to achieve the desired behavior Thanking in advance

Its worth mentioning that application run fine locally with out modifying cacert. This is really confusing me. What am I missing !
Moreover the 3rd party we are integrating with is is signed by verisign.

Answer (score 0):

I went through something similar when upgrading IBM WebSphere versions where all of a sudden the certificate needed to be imported into the application servers trusted store.  SSL as far as I know is third party to java and the jvm itself (ibm's own in my case or openssh in most others).  Thus, you really don't need access to the JVM itself but your middleware on top of the JVM. I don't have direct experience with Grail but if it runs on and application server like JBoss then perhaps through a management interface you are allowed to add certificates to its trusted store similar to I was.  Good Luck.

Comment: Problem is I am using amazon EC2 and cloud foundry and do not have access to the management interfaces. The other thing is when i am running locally I do not see any problem. I tested this with Tomcat, but I am surprised with the error on the server.